# Google Plus & Javascript - Disable scrolling when choosing circles?

Tags: javascript, scroll, google-plus, scroll-lock

I've created a lot of Circles. And so when I hover over the "Add to Circles" google plus button, a small div pops up that allows me to vertically scroll through my circles.

The really cool part is that it disable body scrolling. So when I scroll to the bottom of the circles viewer, the body doesn't budge.

How is this possible with javascript?

(I've found a hacky way to do it:

```
$('body').css({'overflow':'hidden'});
$(document).bind('scroll',function () { 
window.scrollTo(0,0); 
});
```

But Google does it better. The body scroll bar stays in place (it doesn't vanish like my code makes it), and the body is still unscrollable...)

**It's important to note (and so far overlooked) that the scroll bar on the body page has to stay in place. It can't vanish like overflow:hidden makes it, because that jerks all of the page content to the right. Google solves this problem somehow...**

SCREENSHOT: [image]

Comment: Maybe you can add a screenshot? Which page are you exactly talking about?

Comment: Just go to plus.google.com (and login) and check out the Add to Circles area in the right sidebar.

Comment: we had this question quite a few times... try the search function

Comment: @Fender: It hasn't been answered correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript - Hijack page scrolling like Google Plus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924155/javascript-hijack-page-scrolling-like-google-plus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using :

```
$(document).bind('scroll',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```