# Google Plus - Scroll in div, prevent body scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript - Hijack page scrolling like Google Plus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924155/javascript-hijack-page-scrolling-like-google-plus)

Google Plus does this really cool thing on your home page. When you hover over "Add to Circles" (and the popover scrolls vertically, the body scrolling is disabled. So you can scroll up and down in the dropdown circles box, but the page won't move.

**How is it possible to disable page scrollig like this?**